# Insert mirror object using Parse Cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform, nosql

I have a scenario where I need to duplicate an object (after or before saving it to Parse) only changing one field.
The problem is, I can't figure out how to find the stop condition when saving this new object and the afterSave callback getting called again and again.
My object:

```
{
        "createdAt": "2015-02-21T23:25:03.525Z",
        "creator": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "2k9OzzBrPr"
        },
        "date": {
            "__type": "Date",
            "iso": "2015-02-21T22:46:39.048Z"
        },
        "description": "Hdheha",
        "from": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "Sd9B1XyZVL"
        },
        "has_accepted": false,
        "has_answered": false,
        "objectId": "YQCWRo0j2V",
        "status": 0,
        "to": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "2k9OzzBrPr"
        },
        "updatedAt": "2015-02-21T23:25:03.525Z",
        "value": 2.3499999046325684
    }
```

My (try) server code:

```
function saveMirrorDebit(request) {
    var toUser = request.object.get("to");
    var fromUser = request.object.get("from");
    var invertedDebit = request.object;

    var Debit = Parse.Object.extend("Debit");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Debit);
    query.equalTo("parent_debit", {
        __type : "Pointer",
        className : "Debit",
        objectId : invertedDebit.id
    });

    query.find({
        success : function (debit) {
            if (debit) {
                console.log('debito nao nulo');
            } else {
                console.log('debito nulo, criando o espelho invertido');

                var newDebit = new Debit();

                newDebit.set("creator", invertedDebit.get("creator"));
                newDebit.set("from", toUser);
                newDebit.set("to", fromUser);
                newDebit.set("value", -invertedDebit.get("value"));
                newDebit.set("parent_debit", {
                    __type : "Pointer",
                    className : "Debit",
                    objectId : invertedDebit.id
                });

                newDebit.save(null);
            }
        },
        error : function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Which is called on afterSave:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Debit", function (request) {
...
saveMirrorDebit(request);
...
}
```

How can I approach this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling `response.success()` or `response.error()` ?  Cloud functions tend to misbehave when you don't do that.

Comment: Thank you for aswering, now I am calling both responses (on their respective places, edited code) but I'm still struggling with the logic...

Comment: Is afterSave still running repeatedly when an object is saved?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm trying to figure out the stop condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wouldn't recommend you duplicating any object... What are you trying to achieve?

Anyhow, in an `afterSave`, you can achieve what you want. Note that the `beforeSave` could save you one API call.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Debit", function (request) {

    var debit = request.object;
    if (!(debit.has("duplicated"))){
        var Debit = Parse.Object.extend("Debit");
        var duplicated_debit = new Debit();
        duplicated_debit.set("creator", debit.get("creator"));
        duplicated_debit.set("date", debit.get("date"));
        duplicated_debit.set("from", debit.get("from"));
        // repeat as many times as needed, include your "change logic here"

        // that's where the magic happens
        duplicated_debit.set("duplicated",true);
        debit.set("duplicated",true);
        Parse.Object.saveAll([duplicated_debit,debit]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you would suggest me to use beforeSave? How would that end up being? And just to clarify, I need to duplicate to perfmor easier and faster queries. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your queries can be easier with duplicated data.. can you describe? I don't think you need beforeSave. You can easily adapt the code to a beforeSave if you reach into huge issues by reaching the API limit because of this hook

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari, I have simplified the code as you're in an afterSave. Please try the updated code and let me know if you run into any issues

Comment: That worked ! Thank you very much, it solved my problem ! As soon as possible I'll award you the bounty ;)